# Self hosted ASP.NET Core app does not work with SSL

Tags: asp.net-core, https, kestrel

I have created an sample `ASP.NET Core` application using command line:

```
dotnet new
```

and tried to run it utilizing command:

```
dotnet run
```

But, when opening the URL in the browser, it complains that the SSL is invalid.

I can run the program using `Visual Studio` full version without any problem, but can not run it using command line:

```
dotnet run
```

Seems that `Kestrel` which is run by command `dotnet run` needs extra configurations.

Now, the question is how can I run my `ASP.NET Core` application over `https` using `Kestrel`?

I'm on `Dot Net Core 2.2` and `Visual Studio 2019`

Comment: Did you try running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`? That should set up the developer certificate for local development over HTTPS.

Comment: @poke No, but will try and comment here about the results.

Comment: @poke, My machine is messed up with my tweaking with HTTPS but, it seems that your solution is working. Would you mind to present it as an answer? I also found this link useful: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run ASP.NET Core in development mode using `dotnet run`, or from within Visual Studio, then there is already built-in support for a development certificate that allows you to develop right away with HTTPS support.

The development certificate is built-in with the .NET Core SDK and usually it should set it self up when you run the .NET Core SDK for the first time. If that did not work or if you lost the development certificate for some reason, then you can always install it later using the following command:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

This part is also described in the [“Enforcing SSL” chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos) of the official documentation.

Note that the development certicate only applies during development and of course you will need to set up a proper certificate for production later. How that works of course depends on how you are going to host the application later. The different options and how to configure SSL is covered in the [hosting chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `IIS Express` does some works behinds the scense which include configuration of a `SSL` certification. So, I concentrated on `ASP.NET Core`'s internal hosting component which is `Kestrel`.

Firstly, I created and SSL certificate using `PowerShell` by help of this command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName localhost -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

This command creats a certification which I can see it through `management console / certificates` program. For more information see [this](https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/235636308-How-To-Create-a-SHA-256-Self-Signed-Certificate). After creating a new certificate, you are required to export it as a `pfx` file. To do so in the management console use follwing steps:

1. Add `Certificates` snap-in to the management console.
2. Navigate through `Personal\Certifcates`
3. Right click on your newly created certificate and, from "all tasks", select "export"
4. Select the option which says: "Yes, export the private key"
5. You'll see that the `pfx` is automatically selected. Click "Next"
6. Set a password and saving location.
7. You are done with creating a pfx file

Next step is to configure ASP.NET Core to use the `pfx` file which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211286/using-appsettings-json-to-configure-kestrel-listen-port-dotnet-core-2-preview-2):

> ```
> public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
>  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
>  .UseStartup < Startup > ()
>  .UseKestrel((hostingContext, options) => 
>  { 
>   if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment) {
>    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 9001);
>    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 9002, listenOptions => {
>     listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "password");
>    });
>   }
>
>  })
>  .Build();
> ```

Now, the problem should be resolved. If not, try the certificate which is created by the `IIS Express`. This is also available in management console.

Comment: can you maybe also write how you call your application now? do you still use the --urls attribute?

Comment: @CodingYourLife I am on Linux machine nowadays. So, can't test this by now.

Comment: Solved it meanwhile. the --urls attribute is ignored after this change and I changed IPAddress.Loopback to IPAddress.All to get it working

Comment: This was a helpful answer for me.
For .Net 6, after putting the cert in the www folder, do this:
'''
        var webroot = builder.Environment.WebRootPath;
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
    {
        serverOptions.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.UseHttps(webroot + "\\Cert.pfx", "password");
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer was simply that I had to close all instances of Chrome before it started working.  I had Chrome open with a few tabs, independent of my dev site that started up.  It still wasn't working even after installing the dev cert, but when I shut down every browser I had open and then started up a debugging session, it started working with no cert issues.