# Change IP address and port of ASP.NET Core console server for SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I am running a .NET Core SignalR server on a Console Application. With my code below, I can run the server. But since the clients of this server is another IP Address, I need to setup my SignalR server to run on the current PC's IP Address. Upon running this is what I get:

[image]

I need to change the `http://localhost:5000` to current host pc's IP address which is `192.168.1.4` and set the port to `8090`. Please see my code below:

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions => {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SomePolicy", builder => builder
                   .SetIsOriginAllowed(IsOriginAllowed)
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials()
                   .Build()
               );
            });
        }

        private bool IsOriginAllowed(string host)
        {
            var allowedOrigin = Configuration.GetSection("AcceptedOrigin").Get<string[]>();
            return allowedOrigin.Any(origin => origin == host);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors("SomePolicy");
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<RimHub>("/rimHub");
            });
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

On the previous version of SignalR, we can use the `.WithUrl('IPADDRESS')`, but with this new version, I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks @gurkan for wanting to edit questions here. However, please note that proper nouns (e.g. .NET Core SignalR) are not themselves code, and should not be formatted as such. The `inline code device` is useful for small code snippets, short pieces of config, and machine IO.

Comment: It's worth noting also that sentence case is preferred for titles here (see the front page).

Comment: @halfer I prefer like that but of course my prefers are can't be reference for the community. You are right though using it is noticeable at first sight.

Comment: Thanks @gurkan. Yes, if you can use standard formatting, rather than personal formatting preferences, that would be good. I do this too - for example I have to stop myself changing US spellings to UK ones!

Comment: @halfer Oh yes, thanks for your kind suggestions. I'll watch out your notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder, Kestrel is used as web server (see [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_WebHost_CreateDefaultBuilder)).

You can find details at [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#kestrel-in-aspnet-core-apps) to configure Kestrel (e.g. via appsettings.json or in Startup). Examples can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211286/using-appsettings-json-to-configure-kestrel-listen-port-dotnet-core-2-preview-2).

How did you use .WithUrl on the server side in the past? I would rather think that the method is used on the [client side](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#connect-to-a-hub).

Comment: Yes you're right on the client side. Thank you. I'll give it a shot.