# Server certificate error when trying to run a dotnet web app as a service in Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, nginx

I'm running an Ubuntu 22.04 container in proxmox as root.

Created a .net 8.0 web app api on a Windows machine I set the app.urls to the containers IP

```
app.Urls.Add("https://10.0.0.242:7000");
```

Published the app using a Release Configuration Target runtime of portable,

Copied the published folder over to the Ubuntu container.

Running an nginx proxy manager docker container.
Setup the proxy host with our domain name set the scheme to https with the ip address and port 7000 of the Ubuntu machine. Enable Block Common Exploits and WebSocket Support. Get a SSL letsencrypt certificate Enabled Force SSL and HTTP/2 Support.

I go to the ubuntu machine and run `dotnet FRTOOLS.WebhookListener.dll` app runs and I receive POST and GET requests to our proxy domain url as expected.

So now I want to run the app as a service so if things restart or whatever. I created a .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Web API App Listening for Channel Advisor Webhook responses on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/www/data/publish
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /usr/www/data/publish/FRTOOLS.WebhookListener.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-webapi
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

did a

```
systemctl start webhooklistener
```

my logging shows an error
`Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date. To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'.`

So trouble shooting that with dotnet cert trust and everyopther stackoverflow suggestion for the error no fix.

chmod chown the folder so that www-data has permission. still not working?

I can't understand why the app will work for me when running the app in command line with `dotnet` 
but not as a service?

Comment: Forgot to add this warning message I get when running the app from command line.
`The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is not trusted. For information about trusting the ASP.NET Core developer certificate, see https://aka.ms/aspnet/https-trust-dev-cert.`. Which refers you to the dev-certs https --trust and --clean what I first tried troubleshooting when trying to run the app as a service.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I ended up solving my problem. I'm not sure if this method is the accepted standard but it works.

Once I realized what is actually occurring during the build process of a dotnet web application as per the documents here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#default-configuration
I understand now that I can add the .pem server certificates and the url settings for the kestrel server setup in my appsettings.json file

```
"Kestrel": {
   "Certificates": {
     "Default": {
        "Path": "/usr/www/data/listener/publish/certificate/fullchain.pem",
        "KeyPath": "/usr/www/data/listener/publish/certificate/privkey.pem"
     }
   },
   "Endpoints": {
       "Https": {
          "Url": "https://10.0.0.242:7000"
       }
   }
},
```

After creating the LetsEncrypt certificate in nginx proxy manager, I put the unzipped files within my Web Apps published project folder so when transferring files via sftp to my Ubuntu machine it brings the .pem certificates with it.

The path for my .pem are the folder locations of where the my web app is stored within the Ubuntu machine.

The stackoverflow question here
[Using appsettings.json to configure Kestrel listen port Dotnet core 2 preview 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211286/using-appsettings-json-to-configure-kestrel-listen-port-dotnet-core-2-preview-2) 
partially lead me to my answer.

It was getting the certificates and putting them in there correct locations that had me confused.
Also using nginx proxy manager and being able to export the certificates made the process so much easier for me I didn't need to use certbot then openssl to create a .pfx file then copy those files from one container to another.

**But** there is one caveat that this certificate is not password protected! The other future problem is when I need to renew the certificate in 90 days then we'll see the difficulties involved with this method.